# Optional parameter extended on generic class in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, components

Long story short, I have a component which is used in multiple pages, and depending on the page, the input type is different, an array of type inputType[]. In HTML I have a for to iterate over those object in the array, and a check to show some data if object.whateverValue is present in the object.

The issue is that this whateverValue is present in 2 of 3 pages, which will require me to add/extend the generic type to can cover this with a default value for the pages where this key is not present.

I tried the following:

```
export class SmallComponent<T extends {whateverValue: string}[]> implements OnInit {
  @Input() public data: T[] = [];
}
```

and I get the error:  `Property 'whateverValue' does not exist on type 'T'.` from HTML.

How can I add this optional value to my objects when it is not present so I can iterate without those errors? I supposed it will be added as undefined at least if I extend the generic class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a fix myself:

```
  private _tableData: (T & {whateverValue: string})[];

  public get tableData(): (T & {whateverValue: string})[] {
    return this._tableData;
  }

  @Input() public set tableData(tableData: T[]) {
    this._tableData = tableData.map((row: T) => {
      return {
        ...row,
        whateverValue:
          typeof row['whateverValue' as keyof T] === 'string'
            ? row['whateverValue' as keyof T]
            : 'default',
      };
    }) as (T & {whateverValue: string})[];
  }
```

I added a setter/getter for the input with the data I loop on, and even I check if the value is present, otherwise I add a default value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirement, seems a bit confused.
I hope this might help:

```
interface Properties<T>{
  whateverValue?: string
}
class firstObject{

}
class newObject implements Properties<firstObject> {

}
```

You can use `?` operator to tell the class which derives the property, that a specific property might not be there. Of course you need to handle that in the HTML template.

[Playground with code above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAdpmBAZwB4AVAPgG8AoZZAdwAs5IA3aANTgBsBXCAfgBcyAmCigA5lQC%20VBFzgECyGMCiiA8gCMAVhARhqMuQqXIQEOtr0HkwALZYuEexHDL02XPmKr1Ya30wMmQjaSA)